# Character counter breaks after adding EmojiOne Area

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a character counter for my textarea that was working great until I added [EmojiOne Area](https://github.com/mervick/emojionearea). The emoji picker now works great, but my character counter stopped working. For some reason the `keyup` is no longer working off of the ID.

Here is my current code:

#### HTML

```
<textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea> 
<label><span id="chars" class="lead">140</span></label> characters left
```

#### JavaScript

```
/*emojioneArea */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#message").emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom",
    tonesStyle: "bullet"
  });
});

/*Character Counter */
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;

  if (len >= 140) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 140);
    $('#stat span').text(0);
  } else {
    $('#stat span').text(140 - len);
  }
}
countChar($('#message').get(0));
$('#message').keyup(function() {
  countChar(this);
});
```

```js
/*emojioneArea */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#message").emojioneArea({
    pickerPosition: "bottom",
    tonesStyle: "bullet"
  });
});

/*Character Counter */
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;

  if (len >= 140) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 140);
    $('#stat span').text(0);
  } else {
    $('#stat span').text(140 - len);
  }
}
countChar($('#message').get(0));
$('#message').keyup(function() {
  countChar(this);
});
```

```css
.emojionearea-editor:not(.inline) {
  min-height: 8em!important;
}

.emojionearea,
.emojionearea.form-control {
  display: block;
  position: relative !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -moz-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, -webkit-box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.emojionearea .emojionearea-editor {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: inherit;
  color: #59A80B;
  cursor: text;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mervick/emojionearea/master/dist/emojionearea.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<textarea id="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
<label><span id="chars" class="lead">140</span></label> characters left
```

Or view it in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Blunick/euv5Lekn/).

Comment: Sounds like this plugin is messing with your textarea, such that the keystrokes are not going to it. I'd change the event to `input` and see if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found several problem with your code actually. And following is the updated working code with emojionearea and character count.

```
/*emojioneArea */
   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#message").emojioneArea({
                       pickerPosition: "bottom",
                       tonesStyle: "bullet",
                       events: {
                         keyup: function (editor, event) {
                           console.log('event:keyup');
                           countChar(this);
                        }
                      }
               });
    }); 

   /*Character Counter */
        function countChar(val) {
            var len = val.getText().length;
            if (len >= 140) {
                  val.value = val.content.substring(0, 140);
                  $('#chars').text(0);
            } else {
                 $('#chars').text(140 - len);
            }
        }
```

This is the Fiddle link for the same, where you can check it. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/banshi/pm9hkc17/)

Updated Code with Initial load [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/banshi/pm9hkc17/8/)

Comment: Is there a way for it to load the actual character count when the page loads? That functionality was lost with this new code.

Comment: Actually, When the page load, it shows "140 characters left" that is same as what it was previously, so I don't think there is any need to call count method on load.

Comment: I'm saving what they type and the end user can come back to re-edit. So, I'll need it to show the amount left on load.

Comment: Hi, Please check my updated answer, I have added a new fiddle link which include character count at initial load.

Comment: Thank you so much! Very much appreciated.

Comment: How would this go into minus figures?